# How to find number of subnets?

Tags: subnet

How to find the total number of subnets available for one subnet mask?.

For example, take this subnet mask:

`255.255.255.224` and IP address as `192.168.5.139`, book shows that there are **6** subnet for the given subnet mask, ranging from `192.168.5.32` to `192.168.5.192` , how **6** ?

I tried to solve it like this *2^3 = 8* and *8-2 = 6* But I thought that we should subtract *2* only when we find number of hosts (because of network ID and Broadcast).

Why do we subtract 2 for subnets?

Comment: That stems from the time when there were plenty of IPv4 addresses, and we used network classes, which were killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519. The Internet went commercial in 1995, and we saw the writing on the wall, It no longer made sense to waste two subnets for every network.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If a network address is subnetted, the *first subnet* obtained after subnetting the network address is called **subnet zero** and the last subnet obtained is called the **all-ones** subnet.

In your example:

**Network**: 192.168.5.0

**Subnet Mask**: 255.255.255.224

**Subnets**:

```
Subnet            Broadcast
192.168.5.0      192.168.0.31   <-- subnet zero
 
192.168.5.32     192.168.0.63

192.168.5.64     192.168.0.95

192.168.5.96     192.168.0.127

192.168.5.128    192.168.0.159

192.168.5.160    192.168.0.191

192.168.5.192    192.168.0.223

192.168.5.224    192.168.0.255    <-- all ones
```

Traditionally, it was strongly recommended that **subnet zero** and the **all-ones** subnet not be used for addressing.

According to [RFC 950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc950) from 1985:

> "It is useful to preserve and extend the interpretation of these
> special (network and broadcast) addresses in subnetted networks. This
> means the values of all zeros and all ones in the subnet field should
> not be assigned to actual (physical) subnets."

Remember that this is a 1985 recommendation. More than 30 years have passed from then.

Using **subnet zero** for addressing is discouraged because of the confusion inherent in having a *network* `(192.168.5.0)` and a *subnet* `(192.169.5.0)` with indistinguishable addresses, and the **all-ones** subnet for the confusion inherent in having a network and a subnet with identical broadcast addresses `(192.168.5.255)`.

This recommendation was overruled in 1995 by [RFC-1878](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1878) and [RFC-1812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812). So, nowadays we can use all the subnets and the devices' hardware /software support it.

Comment: You are confusing **subnet** and **address**. The first *address* of a subnet is the "all zero" address (the network address) and the last *address* is the all one (broadcast) address. Nothing prevent using the first and last *subnet*

Comment: read this explanation: http://www.routerfreak.com/subnet-zero-and-all-ones-subnet/

Comment: I admit it may relevant to the question, but this date from classful addressing era and is totally deprecated now. This is not relevant to modern networking. Also the question is obviously educational / home working and as such off-topic.

Comment: I added an explanation of how it is a dated recommendation.